# Prevent page from loading before GET request completes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to append a image to a page which sends a GET request to a third party marketing site via the image URL. I will fully admit I don't completely understand how this is accomplished through a GET request, there's no relevant documentation around from this third party API plugin (if that's what its called) but I do know that it sends this GET request that I see under 'Network' in Chrome Dev Tools.

This GET request is working according to the API dashboard I am checking. However the catch is that sometimes the GET request fails and the data is not sent to the server. This happens often the first time I access this page in awhile and it sends this GET request and the route to the image is not cached, the GET request is cancelled because the image is actually a submit tied to a form. What I understand is that the page will load the next page before this GET request is completed and thus the GET request will be cancelled. The subsequent times the GET request returns much faster probably due to the route being cached (I believe anyway) and it goes through successfully.

I'm wondering what can be done so that I wait until this GET request is completed. I tried looking into AJAX and sending this request through that so I can use synchronous calls to GET, but this is depreciated so it is a non-starter. Also it seems that I get a problem with cross-domain access control if I use a AJAX call directly (strangely no problem through accessing the domain through the image call below).

Here is the function that is being called as an onclick() event as part of a form. The element being clicked is an image/submit button tied to that form.

```
function appendImageToBody() {
        var imgTag = document.createElement("IMG");
        var imageURL = 'http://imgur.com/fakeimage';

        imgTag.setAttribute("src", imageURL);
        imgTag.setAttribute("width", "0");
        imgTag.setAttribute("height", "0");
        imgTag.setAttribute("id", "Img");
        document.body.appendChild(imgTag);
}
```

Comment: Does the GET request fire off when the image has been loaded, to track that the page has been viewed (a nice analytics technique)? Are you saying the user browses to another page before the GET request completes, sometimes?

Comment: @Danny Yes it fires off when the image is appended to the body right after the submit image is clicked. This image is actually the submit button for a form so the browser loads the next page before the GET request completes sometimes (returning cancelled status in Dev Tools). It's mostly on the first time where the GET request takes up to 1+ seconds to return. When I reload the page and submit the form the second time it seems it is cached and returns in 300-400 ms, easily loading before the next page loads and thus the GET request returns 200 OK.

Comment: It seems that tracking form submits by loading an image while the next page is loading (and will thus interrupt the GET request) is not the best way to track this. You could load an image on page load (either page 1 or page 2, where the form action redirects to), which would satisfy the analytics. Or, attach an ajax request to the form submit to satisfy the analtyics (you may have tried that, not sure...). But, loading an image after submitting the form and hoping it sends another request seems error-prone. You may want to paste your form-submit code along w/ info about the 3rd party api here.

Answer (score 0):

After a little more digging I put this function in jQuery.onBeforeUnload and the GET request now completes even after the next page loads. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

I suppose this fixes it but I'd still love to understand how/why. The new page reloads when this GET request completes so I am a bit confused how it is appending an image to a non-existing page.